# public event itemcheck() is an event and cannot be called directly. use a 'raiseevent' statement to raise an event

Tags: vb.net

Hi i converted the following c# code to vb.net.

```
public Dropdown(CheckedComboBox ccbParent)
{
this.ccbParent = ccbParent;

InitializeComponent();

this.ShowInTaskbar = false;                     

this.cclb.ItemCheck += new System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventHandler(this.cclb_ItemCheck);
}

private void cclb_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
 if (ccbParent.ItemCheck != null)
  {
    ccbParent.ItemCheck(sender, e);
  }
}
```

Visual Basic

```
Private cclb As CustomCheckedListBox

Public Event ItemCheck As Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventHandler

Public Sub New(ByVal ccbParent As PlexisCheckedComboBox)

 MyBase.New()

 Me.ccbParent = ccbParent

 InitializeComponent()

 Me.ShowInTaskbar = False

 AddHandler cclb.ItemCheck, AddressOf cclb_ItemCheck

End Sub

Private Sub cclb_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs)

If (Not (ccbParent.ItemCheck) Is Nothing) Then

    ccbParent.ItemCheck(sender, e)

End If

End Sub
```

In the converted vb.net code im getting error in the following line as 
 ""

```
If (Not (ccbParent.ItemCheck) Is Nothing) Then

 ccbParent.ItemCheck(sender, e)
```

please help me how to resolve it .

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the error message told you, you have to use the `RaiseEvent` keyword to raise events.

But even then it would not work, since you can't raise events outside of the class the event is declared in (in contrast to C#, where nested classes can raise events of the outer class).

So to solve this add a new method to the outer class called `OnItemCheck` which raises the `ItemCheck` event, and call that method in `cclb_ItemCheck` instead of trying to raise the event directly.